# React (SPFx - Sharepoint Framework): Control order of imported css classes

Tags: css, reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

In my React solution I am using a custom component called [RichText](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/RichText/). The problem with this component is, that one of the styles for `h2` element has different `font-weight` as I would need to. I am trying to override default style of this custom component, but due to the fact that this property is set as `!important` I am unable to do so (as order of custom component style takes precedense over my import). Please refer to image below:

[image]

I have tried the following things to make sure, my CSS class will be loaded later (which should place it hierarchically above the css of custom component):

- Change order of imports at the top of my component (tried to make it first, tried to make it last; nothing worked)
- tried to use lifecycle events (componentDidMount) and dynamically import css then
- tried to load css with timer (e.g. wait 2 seconds and then `import()` class)
- used `:global` identifier in my scss class

Yet nothing has changed the order of this class. Am I missing something or what do I need to do in order to make sure it will be loaded as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I test,if we want to change the text in onChange property,the control will not change the style.
As a workaround,you could try to change the default Bold function font-weight.

Test code:

```
    .richtext strong{
        font-weight: 300!important;
      }

<RichText className={styles.richtext}
          onChange={(text)=>this.onChange(text)}
/>
private onChange = (newText: string) => {
    
  return newText;
}
```

Test result:
[image]
Or you could try to ask for further help in [pnp control github](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues).

Comment: Yes this is a feasible option, however in my case users have very long rich texts (combination of various styles and elements) thus post processing would be quite painful...yet I agree that this would definitely work :) Thank you for your answer